# My Search results are showing up with system name

Tags: search, search-results, alternate-access-mapping

When i search for "mak" in my site collection of sharepoint 2013 on premises. i get results with /in-fe-2013prod/something/mak

i don't want to show my system name in-fe-2013prod instead i want to show up http://abc.com/something/mak

how to change the search result show up using url

Answer (score 2):

Go into the search service associated with the application (Application Management > Manage service applications) and create a new Server Name mapping. Put in something like this:

**Address in index:**

```
http://in-fe-2013prod/
```

**Address in search results:**

```
http://abc.com/
```

This is usually used with an alternate access mapping to control the address your users see vs. what's actually set up in SharePoint, but will work solely on search results without the AAM. Keep in mind that by itself, this will only make users see the 2nd address in the results - when they click on the link they will still go to the 1st address.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do Server Name Mapping, check your Alternate Access Mapping settings. Search generally uses the Default Zone when results come from different AAM zones. Resolve the zones first, then Perform a FULL crawl. I cover this exact issue in my search class: http://bit.ly/abSearch